# Change a div content in position

Tags: jquery, css, animation, scroll, position

I want to change a text depending on a div position.
A picture is worth a thousand words, so here's a gif of what I want :

[image: example of what I wan't]

And here's my code :

https://jsfiddle.net/c0mk2wto/4/

```
<div class="image i_one"></div>
<div class="image i_two"></div>
<div class="image i_three"></div>

<div class="text t_one">One</div>
<div class="text t_two">Two</div>
<div class="text t_three">Three</div>
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one (it is show the main idea how to implement it): https://jsfiddle.net/c0mk2wto/8/

```
var getDivClassByClass = function (className) {
    var divHash = {
      i_one: '.t_one',
      i_two: '.t_two',
      i_three: '.t_three'
    },
    key,
    value,
    classN = '';
    for (key in divHash) {
       console.log(className, key);
       if (className.indexOf(key) >= 0) {
         classN = divHash[key];
         break;  
       }
    }
    return classN;
};

var scroll = function () {
    var images = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.image'));
    var positions = images.map(function (image) {
       var box = image.getBoundingClientRect();
       return {
         imageClass: image.className,
         closestTop: Math.abs(box.top)
       };
    });
    positions.sort(function (p1, p2) {
            return p1.closestTop - p2.closestTop;
    });
    positions.forEach(function (pos, index) {
      var element = document.querySelector(getDivClassByClass(pos.imageClass));
      if (!index) {
         element.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
         element.style.display = 'none';
      }
    });

};

window.addEventListener('scroll', scroll, false);
scroll();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that adding data attribute can solve your issue more easier :)
https://jsfiddle.net/c0mk2wto/10/

```
var targetTop = $(".t_one").position().top;

$(document).ready(function() {
    scrollAnimate(); // for init
}).scroll(function() {
    scrollAnimate();
});

function scrollAnimate() {
    var _scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

    $('.text').addClass("hidden");

    $(".image").each(function() {

        if(targetTop >= $(this).position().top - _scrollTop &&
           targetTop <= $(this).position().top + $(this).height() - _scrollTop) {

            var id = $(this).data("id");
            $(".text[data-id=" + id + "]").removeClass("hidden");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: did you have been add `data-id` to div?
like this :
`<div class="image i_one" data-id="1"></div>`
and also check that jquery library have been completely loaded.

Comment: and `hidden` should be declared as `display: none`